# Which folder to download in FTP in order to download the entire WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I want to transfer my entire WordPress site to a new domain. I am trying to download the site via FTP.
But when I tried to download the / folder directly, it was way too large and even after 4 hours, only two sub-folders were downloaded.
So I want to know exactly which folder to download so I can just upload it in a new server and my site will be transferred.

Should I download /root or /home or /var

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNvMR.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztpqb.png)

Comment: image 2 has : `/home/dawn34645754/html/` ***THIS*** is the folder you should download, the rest is not required. You want all the folders that start with `/wp-` in their names

Answer (score 0):

Compress and download home folder via cpanel. You must also export the wordpress database and create new database on your new host server then import the wordpress database.
You can find more [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/).
Or you can duplicate your wordpress website with the [plugin Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/).
This plugin is easy to use.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying.I don't have cpanel. I am using Filezilla to access the server. Anyway, so I need to download the home folder right?
I tried doing it via the duplicator plugin but the build was failing again and again for some reason. I even changed the maximum execution limit for PHP but it didn't work.
Although I did download the database using 'duplicator', but I wasn't able to do the entire site that's why I am manually doing it using the FTP.

Comment: But I am not sure which all folders do I need to download. /root /home /var /public_html.
That's why I want to confirm it.

Comment: If it is just a base level hosted domain it should be the file level where the files named wp-admin,wp-content, and wp-includes exists. pretty much everything in that folder.

Comment: Okay, but I found that these same folders are located in /root as well as /var.